# code actionscript exporting dynamic animation in avi

Tags: compilation, avi

:)

I have a flash module in a simple webpage.

In that flash module : some graphic elements are defined by the user.

When the user clic on "OK", it should export the animation in .avi format and upload that on a server.

Is it possible to create a AS script for that? (for an avi exportation)

thanks for answer :)